# Dynamic array of structs in C

Tags: c, array, memory-management

Based on some code on internet, I implemented a dynamic array of structures in C.

I am really interested in some feedback on this.  Maybe there are some places where it can cause memory leaks or other pitfalls? (I am also concerned if there can be situation that I free a pointer twice in my case, and how to avoid that)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    char * name;
} Student;

// array of structs
typedef struct
{
    Student *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize)
{
    // Allocate initial space
    a->array = (Student *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(Student));

    a->used = 0;           // no elements used
    a->size = initialSize; // available nr of elements

    // Initialize all values of the array to 0
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<initialSize; i++)
    {
        memset(&a->array[i],0,sizeof(Student));
    }
}

// Add element to array
void insertArray(Array *a, Student element) 
{
    if (a->used == a->size)
    {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (Student *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(Student));
    }

    // Copy name
    a->array[a->used].name = (char*)malloc(strlen(element.name) + 1);
    strcpy(a->array[a->used].name, element.name);

    // Copy ID
    a->array[a->used].ID=element.ID;

    a->used++;
}

void freeArray(Array *a) 
{
    // Free all name variables of each array element first
    for(int i=0; i<a->used; i++)
    {
        free(a->array[0].name);
        a->array[0].name=NULL;
    }

    // Now free the array 
    free(a->array);
    a->array = NULL;

    a->used = 0;
    a->size = 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Array a;
    Student x,y,z;

    x.ID = 20;
    x.name=(char*)malloc(strlen("stud1") + 1);
    strcpy(x.name,"stud1");

    y.ID = 30;
    y.name=(char*)malloc(strlen("student2") + 1);
    strcpy(y.name,"student2");

    z.ID = 40;
    z.name=(char*)malloc(strlen("student3") + 1);
    strcpy(z.name,"student3");

    // Init array
    initArray(&a, 5);   

    // Add elements 
    insertArray(&a, x);  
    insertArray(&a, y);   
    insertArray(&a, z);   

    // Print elements
    printf("%d\n", a.array[0].ID);        
    printf("%s\n", a.array[0].name);  
    printf("%d\n", a.array[1].ID);   
    printf("%s\n", a.array[1].name);   
    printf("%d\n", a.array[2].ID);   
    printf("%s\n", a.array[2].name);  
    printf("%d\n", a.array[3].ID);   
    printf("%s\n", a.array[3].name);   

    // Free array
    freeArray(&a);

    free(x.name);
    free(y.name);
    free(z.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> I am also concerned if there can be situation that I free a pointer twice in my case

... and ...

> Yes just I am more interested in cases when/if there can be for example freeing unallocated memory or freeing already freed memory ...

After a quick inspection it doesn't appear that you free memory more than once:

- `free` statements are only in the `freeArray` and `main` methods
- Each `free(a->array[0].name);` is different because each name is allocated using its own malloc
- `free(a->array)` is only called once
- `freeArray` is only called once
- `free(x.name);` doesn't free the same memory as `free(a->array[0].name);` because `insertArray` allocates new memory for each name

> and how to avoid that

Something which can help (though not guarantee) is to assign NULL to the pointer after you pass it to free.

- It can help, because calling free on a previously-nulled pointer will harmlessly do nothing
- It's not a guarantee, because you might have more than one pointer pointing to the same memory

---

dmcr_code's comment below points out a bug. You wrote,

```
for(int i=0; i<a->used; i++)
{
    free(a->array[0].name);
    a->array[0].name=NULL;
}
```

This should be,

```
for(int i=0; i<a->used; i++)
{
    free(a->array[i].name);
    a->array[i].name=NULL;
}
```

Because you set `a->array[0].name=NULL;` after freeing it, you don't free it twice.

But, you did fail to free the memory associated with `a->array[i].name` for values of `i` larger than 0.

---

> But then how do I protect against that - when array[i].name can contain random value and I try to free it?

To protect yourself:

- Either, don't let it contain a random value (e.g. ensure that it's either a valid pointer, or zero)
- Or, don't use it (e.g. ensure that your `a->used` logic is correct so that you don't touch elements which you haven't used/initialized).

> is memset in the initArray method fine for that?

memset is good:

- You could use calloc instead of malloc to avoid having to use memset as well
- You could use memset on the whole array at once instead of using memset on each element of the array

memset in initArray isn't enough. It's enough to begin with, but there's a realloc in insertArray. So to be good enough, you'd also need to use memset after realloc (to memset the as-yet-unused end of the newly-reallocated array; without using memset on the beginning of the reallocated array, which already contains valid/initialized/used elements).

> the only unclear part that remains from your response is how to memset realloced array

Your current code in initArray says,

```
// Initialize all values of the array to 0
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<initialSize; i++)
{
    memset(&a->array[i],0,sizeof(Student));
}
```

Another way to do that would be:

```
// Initialize all elements of the array at once: they are contiguous
memset(&a->array[0], 0, sizeof(Student) * initialSize);
```

The memset statement to add to insertArray would be:

```
if (a->used == a->size)
{
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = (Student *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(Student));
    // Initialize the last/new elements of the reallocated array
    for(unsigned int i = a->used; i<a->size; i++)
    {
        memset(&a->array[i],0,sizeof(Student));
    }
}
```

Or:

```
if (a->used == a->size)
{
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = (Student *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(Student));
    // Initialize the last/new elements of the reallocated array
    memset(&a->array[a->used],0,sizeof(Student) * (a->size - a->used));
}
```

> and this comment: "It's not a guarantee, because you might have more than one pointer pointing to the same memory " would be nice if you can address that too

This is safe:

```
void* foo = malloc(10);
free(foo);
// protect against freeing twice
foo = NULL;
// this is useless and strange, but harmless
free(foo);
```

This is not safe:

```
void* foo = malloc(10);
void* bar = foo;
free(foo);
// protect against freeing twice
foo = NULL;
// this is useless and strange, but harmless
free(foo);
// but this is dangerous, illegal, undefined, etc.
// because bar is now pointing to memory that has already been freed
free(bar);
```

Comment: There should be `free(a->array[i].name);`. Also tricky case is if say `a->array[i].name` contains some random garbage value and I try to free it right? (here checking for NULL won't help). ps. and I didn't I think fully understand your last bullet

Comment: @dmcr_code Well done.

Comment: Thanks for cheer up!. But then how do I protect against that - when array[i].name can contain random value and I try to free it? is `memset` in the `initArray` method fine for that? (probably not.. need to think a bit about it myself more)

Comment: "But, you did fail to free the memory associated with a->array[i].name for values of i larger than 0" this I didn't get.. :(

Comment: You called `free(a->array[0].name);` but never call `free(a->array[1].name);`

Comment: @dmcr_code I updated my answer to talk about memset

Comment: aa yes but the realloced array I am not freeing then fully, I just free the `used` part ..

Comment: the only unclear part that remains from your response is how to memset realloced array and this comment: "It's not a guarantee, because you might have more than one pointer pointing to the same memory
" would be nice if you can address that too

Comment: @dmcr_code I edited my answer again

Comment: ok I think after incorporating your comments and my code, the code should be pretty safe right? I will check it a bit more later when implement it; thanks for feedback and effort

Answer (score 5):

I have 3 suggestions.

- If you need to allocate memory and initialize it to zero use `calloc`.
  Using `calloc` is better than using `malloc + memset`

  So change your `initArray` function like:

  ```
  void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize)
  {
     // Allocate initial space
     a->array = (Student *)calloc(initialSize , sizeof(Student));

     a->used = 0;           // no elements used
     a->size = initialSize; // available nr of elements
  }
  ```
- Single character variable names are very bad. Use proper names for variables and follow naming conventions.
- In your code you are only creating and adding 3 objects. But you are trying to print the details of 4th object. (Array index is starting from zero, so index 3 means 4th object)

  ```
  printf("%d\n", a.array[3].ID);   
  printf("%s\n", a.array[3].name);
  ```

Comment: For your second point, you should add "unless it is a loop index/iterator".

Comment: Yes, I was also interested more from memory management point of view etc..

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you tried to fix a bug in [Rev 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/44649/4).  (Editing the question after asking it is discouraged on Code Review.)  However, it's still wrong.  Hint: `i` is an unused variable in the for-loop.

`malloc()` followed by `strcpy()` could be replaced by `strdup()`.

Comment: Yes you are right, should be `i` instead of 0

Comment: Yes just I am more interested in cases when/if there can be for example freeing unallocated memory or freeing already freed memory ...

Comment: `strdup` is no standard C. If I'm not mistaken, it's a POSIX function. Since there is a `#include "stdafx.h"`, I bet that the system used is Windows, and `strdup` may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the `realloc` call in `insertArray()` can fail, and if it does, your array will be corrupt.